# Как обновить пользовательское поле заказа в Bitrix с помощью rest api?

Tags: битрикс, api, rest, битрикс24

Как обновить пользовательское поле параметра заказа в Bitrix с помощью rest api?

Стоит задача: в crm bitrix, с помощью rest api внести данные в пользовательское поле параметра заказа. Каким методом можно это решить?

Answer (score -2):

```
array(
'id' => $sale['result']['order']['id'],
'propertyValues' => array(
    array(
    'orderPropsId' => $sale['result']['order']['propertyValues'][0]['orderPropsId'],
    'value' => 'tets'
    )
)
```

Comment: таким способом есть только доступ к свойствам типа Property***, нужен доступ к UF_CRM_*********